# Django models, deserialize PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a microservice application, which needs to pass an object from service to service, and the receiver needs to save that object to the db. The object I am trying to pass has a field which is a foreign key to another table. That is:

`class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    id=models.CharField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)`

class PrimaryModel(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rel_model=models.ForeignKey(RelatedModel)

class RelatedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '**all**'
        model = RelatedModel

class PrimarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rel_model = RelatedSerializer()

```
class Meta:
    fields = '__all__'
    model = PrimaryModel
```

However, in this case, the serializer on the receiving end was invalid, saying that the related model already existed in the db.

I tried using PrimaryKeyRelatedField, but then the receiving serializer does not contain the `rel_model` at all.

How can I deserialize the related field in the receiving serializer?

Comment: Could you show the view please

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your serializer like this,

```
class RelatedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = RelatedModel
        fields = ('name', )

class PrimarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    rel_model = RelatedSerializer()
    class Meta: 
        model = PrimaryModel 
        fields = ('rel_model', )
```

When posting data through serializer, `id` cannot be passed as it is primary key field.